Quickly solving a system of integral equations using numerical methods/ analytical way to speed up
I am not sure if this is more suitable for math stackexchange or stackoverflow but here we go: I have a system of integral equations with unknowns $\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_5$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x_1-\theta_1)(1-\Phi(x_1-\theta_2))(1-\Phi(x_1-\theta_3))(1-\Phi(x_1-\theta_4))(1-\Phi(x_1-\theta_5))\,dx_1=0.1,$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x_2-\theta_2)(1-\Phi(x_2-\theta_1))(1-\Phi(x_2-\theta_3))(1-\Phi(x_2-\theta_4))(1-\Phi(x_2-\theta_5))\,dx_2=0.15,$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x_3-\theta3)(1-\Phi(x_3-\theta_1))(1-\Phi(x_3-\theta_2))(1-\Phi(x_3-\theta_4))(1-\Phi(x_3-\theta_5))\,dx_3=0.23,$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x_4-\theta4)(1-\Phi(x_4-\theta_1))(1-\Phi(x_4-\theta_2))(1-\Phi(x_4-\theta_3))(1-\Phi(x_4-\theta_5))\,dx_4=0.2,$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x_5-\theta5)(1-\Phi(x_5-\theta_1))(1-\Phi(x_5-\theta_2))(1-\Phi(x_5-\theta_3))(1-\Phi(x_5-\theta_4))\,dx_4=0.32,$$
where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are the probability density function and the cumulative density function of the standard normal variable respectively. So the general form of the equation has the form
$$\pi_i=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{j\not=i}(1-\Phi(x_i-\theta_j))\phi(x_i-\theta_i)\,dx_i.$$
and the $\pi_i$'s sum to 1.
I would like to solve this system of integral equations numerically and quickly. Right now I am using the fsolve function from the scipy package in python. It works fine but it's incredibly slow (about 10 minutes to solve for one system and i have thousands of such systems). I would like to ask is there any mathemstical properties we can exploit (symmetry/ analytical tricks/ properties of $\phi, \Phi$) or any algorithms that can speed up the computation? (since the equations look quite symmetrical and it's given by well-known functions)
Thank you so much in advance.

You realize that if $\theta_i$ is a solution, then so is $\theta_i+\theta$ for every $\theta\in\mathbb R$, right? So you can put $\theta_1=0$ and thus both reduce the dimension from 5 to 4 and ensure the uniqueness of the solution. Both may accelerate the standard solving routine a bit. But I'll think what else can be done nevertheless :-).

@fedja, oh yes! thank you so much!

The conjugate gradient ascent seems to work fairly decently (definitely way under 10 minutes :lol:). Do you want the details? I program in Asymptote (which is slow) but I can convert to C++ if you want and see the actual time needed for solving 1000 equations before posting.

@fedja I have never heard of conjugate gradient ascent before but would love to learn more. I program in Python cuz my original data is given in the form of Pandas dataframe.

Then just wait a bit: I'm a little busy today :-). Just a quick question. I presume that your datasets are reasonable (like all probabilities are not too close to $0$), and the standard machine precision of $10^{-15}$ is fine. If not, one would have to worry about some purely programming issues. I thought of learning Python, but when I discovered that the ability to count spaces on the empty page correctly is a prerequisite, I felt somewhat repelled, which is a pity because it is so widespread now... OK, I'll post something today in the evening or tomorrow.

It is time to present the outline of what is going on here.
Let me denote by $f(z)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$ the density of the standard Gaussian distribution and by $F(z)=\int_z^{+\infty}f(u)\,du$ the "complementary cumulative function" of the Gaussian. We are interested in solving the system
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}f_j(x-\theta_j)\left[\prod_{k\ne j}F(x-\theta_k)\right]\,dx=\pi_j
$$
for $\theta_j$, where the indices run from $1$ to $n$ ($n=5$ in the OP) and $\sum_j\pi_j=1$. The meaning of these integrals is pretty simple: we consider the variance $1$ Gaussians $\xi_j$ on the line with the means $E[\xi_j]=\theta_j$ and want to find the means to that the event that $\xi_j$ is the least of $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ has the prescribed probability $\pi_j$.
We can view this system in a slightly different way, however. Note that everything is translation invariant, so we can set $\theta_n=0$. Also it will be convenient to assume that $\pi_1\le \pi_2\le\dots \le\pi_n$. Technically what will be useful below is only that $\pi_n$ is the largest of the probabilities, but why not to arrange in the increasing order then? From common sense considerations it would follow that then $\theta_1\ge\dots\ge\theta_{n-1}\ge \theta_n=0$. Now with respect to the first $n-1$ variables, the equations read
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial\theta_j} I(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{n-1})=0
$$
where
$$
I(theta)=I(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{n-1})=\int_{\mathbb R}F(x)\left[-1+\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}F_j(x)\right]\,dx-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\pi_j\theta_j
$$
Such system reeks of the extremal problem and, indeed, it is easy to convince ourselves that $I(\theta)$ tends to $-\infty$ when $|\theta|\to\infty$. Indeed, the integral is roughly speaking $J(\theta)=\min(0,\min_j \theta_j)$ (up to a bounded additive term; $J$ is what we get if we replace $F$ by the flipped Heaviside function), and  $J(\theta)-\sum_j\pi_j\theta_j\le -\pi_n|\min\theta_j|$, so if $\min\theta_j$ is large negative, so is $J(\theta)$. However if the minimum stays bounded, then the subtraction of $\pi_j\theta_j$ drives us down when $|\theta|\to\infty$, so we are fine again. Thus, a point of maximum of $I(\theta)$ exists and solves our equations. So instead of a general system solver, we can use the maximizer. I suspect that even if you use some built-in general maximizer, you'll have an advantage already, but I'm an old school guy, so we'll design a custom-built one here.
The first problem is that we have to compute integrals with high precision. Fortunately, our functions are entire of order 2 and decaying fast on the line. The usual contour shift mumbo-jumbo talls us that $|F(z)|\le e^{(\Im z)^2/2}$ on the plane (just integrate along the horizontal ray from $z$ to $+\infty$. Also $\int_{\mathbb R+it} |f(z)||dz|\le e^{t^2/2}$. Hence, the Fourier transform $\widehat G_j(y)=\int_{\mathbb R}G_j(x)e^{-ixy}\,dx$ of $G_j(x)=f_j(x-\theta_j)\prod_{k\ne j}F(x-\theta_k)$ is bounded by $e^{nt^2/2}e^{yt}$ for every $t\in\mathbb R$. Optimizing with respect to $t$, we get $|\widehat G_j(y)|\le e^{-y^2/(2n)}$. Now, by the Poisson summation formula,
$$
|h\sum_\Lambda G_j(x)-\widehat G_j(0)|\le \sum_{k\ne 0}|\widehat G_j(2\pi h^{-1}k)|
$$
where $\Lambda$ is any infinite two-sided arithmetic progression with step $h$.  Using our estimate for the Fourier transform, we see that if $h$ is not too large, the RHS here is not much greater than $2e^{-2\pi^2/(nh^2)}$. I chose $h^2=\frac 1{5n}$ ($\frac 15$ for $n=5$) so my accuracy in the integral computations here is $e^{-10\pi^2}\le  10^{-42}$, which should be enough for all practical purposes, though, if it isn't, you can reduce the step a bit more any time you want.
Now the infinite progression is still too much. Fortunately, $f(x)$ decays fast too, so I restrict the progression to the part contained in $t_j-10,t_j+10$. The error I get is determined by the size of $e^{-x^2/2}$ outside this interval, i.e., $e^{-50}\le 10^{-21}$, which is still way below the precision of float type ($\approx 10^{-15}$ in most programming languages). Again, if you need better accuracy, you know what to do.
Hence, in the case of $n=5$, I can replace all integrals we care about by sums of $20/(1/5)=100$ terms, which seems decent enough though one should remember that those terms include evaluations of erf(), which is quite expensive (if you ever tried to implement the error function yourself with machine precision, you should know that it is quite a headache).
Now which maximization technique to choose? Since everything is smooth, I decided to go for the conjugate gradient ascent (usually it is called "descent" because the convention in the textooks is to look for the minimal rather than maximal value). A very good explanation of the method can be found at https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2022/03/20/conjugate-gradient-descent/ (and in several textbooks on convex optimization, of course, but most of those are behind the paywall). If you find it hard to read, I'll attempt my own explanation, but now I want to attract the attention to just one point that, IMHO, is usually underemphasized (if emphasized at all). The iteration procedure in $\mathbb R^n$ for a smooth function $H$ is as follows: you start with the initial guess $x_0$ and then choose the direction $u_0=\nabla H(x_0)$. Then we maximize $H(x_0+tu_0)$ arriving at a new point $x_1$. From $x_1$, we move in the direction $u_1=\nabla H(x_1)+\frac{\langle\nabla H(x_1),\nabla H(x_1)-\nabla H(x_0)\rangle}{\langle\nabla H(x_0),\nabla H(x_0)\rangle}u_0$   and that update of the direction is repeated from there on. If the function were a pure negative definite quadratic form, after $n$ steps the algorithm would arrive at the dead center (the point of maximum). In general it will end up at a point much closer to the point of maximum, from where we can start all over. $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ here is a scalar product in $\mathbb R^n$. The point I want to make is that you are free to choose which one and this choice matters (of course, the gradient should be defined with respect to the chosen scalar product as well by the usual rule $DH(v)=\langle\nabla H,v\rangle$. It turns out that for our purposes the appropriate choice is
$$
\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_k \frac{u_kv_k}{\pi_k}
$$
and that is implemented in the new version of the code. Since that scalar product requires multiplication of larger numbers, I reduced the requested precision to $10^{-12}$: otherwise numerical rounding errors may be larger. If you want higher accuracy, use the mpmath package and then you can get it with any precision you want, but I should warn you that mpmath arithmetic is much slower than the normal one.
The rest is routine: to maximize $H(x+tu)$ I just solve $\frac d{dt}H(x+tu)=\langle u,\nabla H(x+tu)\rangle=0$ by "guarded quasi-Newton" (the corresponding lines should be self-explanatory), etc.
Note the change in arguments and output of SLV() from the first draft. Now it takes a full vector of probabilities (of any length in any order) and the desired precision, and then outputs the vector of $\theta$'s corresponding to all probabilities including $0$ in the same order (it really works with the reduced list from which the largest probability has been removed, but I took care of all rearrangements for you)
As usual, feel free to ask questions if something is still unclear.
import math
import random
import time


def F(x):
    return (1-math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))/2
def f(x): 
    return math.exp(-x*x/2)/math.sqrt(2*math.pi)

def abss(p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(abs(p[k]))
    return q;

def mult(a,p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(a*p[k])
    return q;

def add(a,p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(a[k]+p[k])
    return q


def dot(u,v,pp):
    s=0
    for k in range(len(u)):
       s+=u[k]*v[k]*pp[k]
    return s;

def grad(t,pp):
    h=math.sqrt(1/5/(len(pp)+1))
    g=[]

    for k in range(len(pp)):
        g.append(-pp[k])
        beg=t[k]-10
        end=t[k]+10
        qq=math.ceil((end-beg)/h)
        for q in range(qq):
            x=beg+q*h
            ss=F(x)
            for m in range(len(pp)):
                if k==m:
                    ss*=f(x-t[m])
                else:
                    ss*=F(x-t[m])
            g[k]+=ss*h;
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        g[k]/=pp[k]
    return g

def iint(t,pp):
    h=0.1
    ss=0
    for k in range(1):
        beg=min(min(t),0)-10
        end=max(max(t),0)+10
        qq=int((end-beg)/h)
        for q in range(qq):
            x=beg+q*h
            s=1; 
            for m in range(len(pp)):
                s*=F(x-t[m])
            ss+=(s-1)*F(x)*h
        for k in range(len(pp)):
            ss-=pp[k]*t[k]
    return ss


def SLV(ppp, eps):
    kk=0
    maxx=ppp[0]
    for k in range(len(ppp)):
        if ppp[k]>maxx:
            kk=k
            maxx=ppp[k]
    print(ppp)
    pp=ppp[:kk]+ppp[kk+1:]
    print("################")
    
    t=[]
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        #t.append(0)
        t.append(math.sqrt(2*math.log(1/pp[k])))
        
    u=grad(t,pp)
    mm=0
    while mm<=50*len(pp) and sum(abss(grad(t,pp)))>eps:
        mm+=1
        if mm%len(pp)==1:
            pass
            #print(mm, sum(abss(grad(t,pp))), sum(abss(t)))
            #x=str(input())
        s=min(1,1/sum(abss(u)))
        cnt=0
        while dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(s,u)),pp),pp)>0 and s*sum(abss(u))<len(u):
            s*=2
            cnt+=1
        
        a=0
        b=s
        beg=a
        end=b
        A=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(a,u)),pp),pp)
        B=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(b,u)),pp),pp)
        k=0
        while k<20 and abs(A-B)>eps*max(abs(A),abs(B)):
            mid=(beg+end)/2
            if dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(mid,u)),pp),pp)>0:
                beg=mid
            else:
                end=mid
            
            c=max(beg-eps,min(end+eps,b+(B/(A-B))*(b-a)))
            C=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(c,u)),pp),pp)
            if abs(a-c)>abs(b-c) and abs(b-c)>0:
                a=b
                A=B
                b=c
                B=C
            else:
                b=a
                B=A
                a=c
                A=C
            if C>0:
                beg=max(beg,c)
            else:
                end=min(end,c)
            k+=1
                
        s=c
            
        oldgrad=grad(t,pp)
        t=add(t,mult(s,u))
        newgrad=grad(t,pp)
        uold=mult(1,u)
        u=mult(1,newgrad)
        if mm%len(pp)!=1:
            u=add(u,mult(dot(newgrad, add(newgrad,mult(-1,oldgrad)),pp)/dot(oldgrad,oldgrad,pp),uold))

    
    ss=sum(abss(grad(t,pp)))
    print(ss, mm)
    tt=t[:kk]
    tt.append(0)
    t=tt+t[kk:]
    print(t)
    if ss>eps:
        x=str(input("Failure! Press enter to continue"))
    print("****************") 
    return t


T=time.time()
random.seed(int(T))

n=6

for uuu in range(3):
    pp=[]
    for k in range(n):
        pp.append(random.uniform(0,1)**3+1/10.0**8)
    D=sum(pp)
    for k in range(n):
        pp[k]/=D
    print(uuu)
    print("")
    
    eps=1/10.0**12
    SLV(pp,eps)

print("Done in ", time.time()-T, " seconds")


This is very smart, thank you so much for your help!

@Ishigami OK, I modified the program a bit so that it is more stable and can handle small probabilities as well without too many iterations. I'm running the final tests now. If everything works as I expect, I'll update the code and post the explanation of why and how it works today or tomorrow :-)

Thank you so much. Actually my original dataset has many such systems of integral equations with different number of unknown per system, this is my original question: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12367/fastest-way-to-solve-many-systems-of-integral-equations-using-python
I have been trying to implement your code into my but without much success. I'm going to keep trying. Thank you so much for your help!

@Ishigami I posted the explanation and the new code. "I have been trying to implement your code into my but without much success" Now you can do any number of $\pi$'s with my SLV(). Just read attentively the last paragraph not to get confused about what should be put into it and what it returns. I'm a bit perplexed about your statement: all you need is to import my code into your file as a separate module, use the SLV() function on your data and collect the output. What exactly is the difficulty you experience with it?

@Ishigami I made it super-easy: put any full list of probabilities (of any reasonable length) and the precision you want into SLV() (you are responsible for checking that the probabilities add up to 1 though!) and get the vector of all $\theta$'s including $0$ returned in the same order. You no longer need to think how it works at all to add it to any existing code.

Thank you so much! That's a lot to take in. This will take some time for me to absorb as I am not a programmer by training but thank you so much for your help. Just one quick question, I just tried to run the code real quick but I got the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' for line 47 and 170.

@Ishigami I copied the code from my post and ran it on https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ It compiled and worked perfectly fine, so I cannot reproduce the problem on my end (it compiles fine on my machine too). Make sure that you copied everything correctly. If it still doesn't work for you, let me know what compiler/shell you are using.

@Ishigami A friend of mine tried it on his computer and it worked fine too. It looks like the problem is on your end somehow. We can try to debug it together, but if you have programmer friends or colleagues, it might be easier to bother them. :-)

I tried to run the code on google colab and my local sublime text and it works on sublime but gives the error on colab. As it turns out, for some weird reason, colab shifted some of the backspaces and it recognises minus ten - 10 to negative ten -10. Anyway it works perfectly now. I can't thank you enough for this, I could never have come up with this by myself so many thanks!

@Ishigami As it turns out, for some weird reason, colab shifted some of the backspaces He-he. I told you that the pre-requisite for programming in Python is the ability to correctly count spaces on a blank sheet of paper. Colab obviously failed that pre-requisite. You are most cordially welcome. Since I spared you some noticeable time, I guess it is OK to request that you also spend some time honestly trying to understand what is going on here, so that the next time you will be able to come up with something like this by yourself. :-)

@fedja Nice solution! Just one small thing: shouldnt $I(\theta)$ be $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} F_j(x),dx - \sum _{j=1}^{n-1} \pi_j \theta_j$?

@Apook Nope. That one diverges!

@fedja sorry but i'm a little bit confused. If $I(\theta)=I(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{n-1})=\int_{\mathbb R}F(x)\left[-1+\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}F_j(x)\right],dx-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\pi_j\theta_j$, then isn't $\partial I/\partial \theta_i = \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x)\prod_{j\not= i}F_j(x),dx - \pi_i$?

@Apook You forgot to multiply by $\varphi_i(x)$ in the integrand.
